# Why is /dev/null needed to run asynchronous jobs in busybox sh?

Tags: busybox, subshell, null

I'm curious why this special device is needed to fork the command and run it asynchronously in the minimal Busybox shell.

```
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Debian 1:1.30.1-4) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

/bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
/ #
/ # echo Hello && sleep 2s && echo World &
/bin/sh: / # can't open '/dev/null': No such file or directory

/ #
/ # mknod /dev/null c 1 3 && chmod 666 /dev/null
/ # echo Hello && sleep 2s && echo World &
/ # Hello
World

/ #
```

Comment: /dev/null is the location you direct output to if you don’t want to see it. Can you explain what you are trying to do

Comment: @PonJar They are using the busybox tools on a system with no or few devices in `/dev`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the implementation](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/c8c1fcdba163f264a503380bc63485aacd09214c/shell/ash.c#L5134) of the shell in busybox:

```c
/*
 * Fork off a subshell.  If we are doing job control, give the subshell its
 * own process group.  Jp is a job structure that the job is to be added to.
 * N is the command that will be evaluated by the child.  Both jp and n may
 * be NULL.  The mode parameter can be one of the following:
 *      FORK_FG - Fork off a foreground process.
 *      FORK_BG - Fork off a background process.
 *      FORK_NOJOB - Like FORK_FG, but don't give the process its own
 *                   process group even if job control is on.
 *
 * When job control is turned off, background processes have their standard
 * input redirected to /dev/null (except for the second and later processes
 * in a pipeline).
 *
 * Called with interrupts off.
 */
```

Note "input redirected to /dev/null".  Since subshells have their standard input redirected from `/dev/null` (and it will be, since job control is turned off, which it will be because `/dev/tty` is also not accessible), you'd get an error if that device file is not accessible.